# I am not able to fetch facebook user information in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am new to i phone programming using below code i am fetching information form Facebook.
But problem is when ever if click on button it going to facebook app asking facebook user name and password after that it show same view.But here i am fetching user information but iam not able to fetch information.Its opening facebook page after that coming back to same page.Again if i click also it repeating same thing.Can any one tell how to slove this.

```
 FBLoginView *fbLoginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]];

    //loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 2, 2);
    // loginview.frame = loginWithFbButton.frame;

    fbLoginview.frame = CGRectMake(30, 10, 200, 30);
    for (id obj in fbLoginview.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            loginWithFbButton =  obj;
            loginWithFbButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);

            // UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImg.png"];
            [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:69.0/255.0 green:115.0/255.0 blue:185.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
            [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginWithFbButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

            //   [loginWithFbButton addTarget:self action:@selector(LoginWithFacebookk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [loginWithFbButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
            [loginWithFbButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:227.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:0.6].CGColor];
            //  [loginWithFbButton sizeToFit];

            loginWithFbButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            loginWithFbButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

            [loginWithFbButton setTitle:@"         Get info from Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginWithFbButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
            loginWithFbButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            loginWithFbButton.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            loginWithFbButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            CAGradientLayer *gradient1 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
            gradient1.frame = loginWithFbButton.bounds;

            UIColor *startColour1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:46.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
            UIColor *endColour1 = [UIColor  colorWithRed:46.0/255.0 green:119.0/255.0 blue:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

            gradient1.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColour1 CGColor], (id)[endColour1 CGColor], nil];
            [loginWithFbButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient1 atIndex:0];


            [fbLoginview addSubview:loginWithFbButton];
        }

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
            loginLabel.text = nil;
            loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 26);
        }
    }

  //  fbLoginview.delegate = self;

    [loginTempview3 addSubview:fbLoginview];
```

Comment: Where is facebook code ?

Answer (score 0):

For fetching user information use Facebook graph API

Please have a look of this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implement facebook delegate methods,

```
fbLoginview.delegate = self;
```

And implement this method to get user information

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    // here we use helper properties of FBGraphUser to dot-through to first_name and
    // id properties of the json response from the server; alternatively we could use


    NSLog(@"user :%@",user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't your problem! Nobody is able to post or like or comment on Facebook.. That could be the reason... Maybe it works well in a hour again!